# Tcp client doesn't receive data

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

In Short -

- Client successfully connects to server
- Client successfully sends data to server
- Server Successfully reads data sent to him
- Server sends data back to client (or at least debugger reaches method
  successfully and continues operating after executing it)
- Client has no idea about data sent to him

Basic idea of what I'm doing in server : Ask prompt to ask for how many clients server will accept, create according number of threads which are waiting for socket connection and when communication starts.

On Client - connect to server, ask to input user's name start communicating by asking user to input their message.

Tried as well sending bytes directly to socket created for client, but still no success.

Client and Server projects/classes : https://gist.github.com/karosas/8ce2d537359d4e7c5e86

Comment: You are closing the connection.  You should never let server close connection.  The client should always open and close connection.  The client should send a message to server before closing so server can stop processing.  The server should wait for close event before stopping application to prevent any race conditions.  Every message should be terminated (or include a byte count) so receiving side of connection knows when message ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You arent flushing the streamwriter in the sendtoall method.